# Nested Horizontal List View

Tags: flutter, stacked

I have a dynamic list of categories.

I have a dynamic list of products for each category.

My lit view builder displays the list of categories vertically.  Now for each category, it makes a request to my server to fetch and display the products under the category.

This works, however vertical scrolling is choppy and I see the following error a lot in my debug console:

```
════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
D/ViewRootImpl@c4f27c2[MainActivity]( 4296): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@c4f27c2[MainActivity]( 4296): ViewPostIme pointer 1
Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

Now this tells me I am doing something wrong here.

This is my products view, I fetch the product categories from server on load:

```
class ProductsView extends ViewModelBuilderWidget<ProductsViewModel> {
  @override
  bool get reactive => true;

  @override
  bool get createNewModelOnInsert => false;

  @override
  bool get disposeViewModel => true;

  @override
  void onViewModelReady(ProductsViewModel vm) {
    vm.getCategories();
    super.onViewModelReady(vm);
  }

  @override
  Widget builder(BuildContext context, vm, Widget child) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
      child: vm.isBusy
          ? ShimmerList(
              type: ShimmerType.list,
              count: 5,
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: vm.categories.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return CategoryItem(category: vm.categories[index]);
              },
            ),
    )));
  }

  @override
  ProductsViewModel viewModelBuilder(BuildContext context) =>
      ProductsViewModel();
}
```

This is the category item widget:

```
class CategoryItem extends ViewModelWidget<ProductsViewModel> {
  final Category category;

  const CategoryItem({Key key, this.category})
      : super(key: key, reactive: false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, vm) {
    return Column(children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child:
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
          Text(category.name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
          InkWell(
            child: Text(
              'See All',
              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF8BC34A), fontSize: 18),
            ),
            onTap: () {},
          )
        ]),
      ),
      ProductsList(
        category: category,
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

This is my Products list view:
For each category I make a request to my server to fetch the underlying products.

```
class ProductsList extends ViewModelWidget<ProductsViewModel> {
  final Category category;

  const ProductsList({Key key, this.category}) : super(key: key, reactive: false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, vm) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: vm.getProducts(category),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Product> products = snapshot.data;
            return Container(
                height: 190,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: products.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black26,
                                blurRadius: 2.0,
                                spreadRadius: 0.0,
                                offset: Offset(
                                    2.0, 2.0), // shadow direction: bottom right
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                              child: Image.network(
                                products[index].thumbnail,
                                width: 110,
                                height: 160,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              )),
                        ),
                        products[index].currentPrice > 0
                            ? Text('GHS ${products[index].currentPrice}')
                            : Text('Free')
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ));
          } else {
            return Text('Hey');
          }
        });
  }
}
```

I am using a future builder to fetch and return the results for each category and display the horizontal list of products.

What I want to know now is how to implement this feature correctly and efficiently so I do not get the above error and my users can get a smooth scrolling experience.

```
Future<List<Product>> getProducts(Category category) async {
  setBusyForObject(category, true);
  List<Book> books;
  if (productsByCategories[category.slug] == null) {
    books = await _productService.getPublishedByCategory(category.slug);
    productsByCategories[category.slug] = books;
    setBusyForObject(category, false);
    return products;
  } else {
    products = productsByCategories[category.slug];
  }

  return products;
}
```

Comment: can you post whats inside `getProducts(category)` ?

Comment: Hi, have updated my post.

Comment: I was trying to dig where you called setState, is there?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are facing is calling your future in the build method like this:

```
 future: vm.getProducts(category)
```

If you look at the [documentation of FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) it says:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
> State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or
> State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the
> State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the
> FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the
> FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt,
> the asynchronous task will be restarted.

You should declare Future variable before your build method, then pass that variable in future builder, that way it want be called on every rebuild.

For example

```
Future myFuture = vm.getProducts(category);

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context, vm) {
   return FutureBuilder(
       future: myFuture,
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
       ...
```

Henok pointed you in the right direction, setState is called in setBusyForObject method which is called because of bad use of FutureBuilder.